# Dominating function of $f_n(x)=\frac{nx\sin(x)}{1+(nx)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Tags: limits, measure-theory, definite-integrals

I'd like to use the dominated Convergence theorem to solve $\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{nx\sin(x)}{1+(nx)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \, dx$ but am a bit stuck on actually proving that $f_n(x)$ is dominated (meaning there is an integrable function $g(x)$ such that $|f_n(x)| < g(x) \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$). So far I have $|f_n(x)| \leq \biggl|\frac{nx}{1+(nx)^{3/2}}\biggr| \leq \biggl|\frac{nx}{(nx)^{3/2}}\biggr| = \Bigl|\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx}}\Bigr|$ but I don't really know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost done as

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \ dx$$ converges.